# How do I render a radio group using form->field

Tags: php, lithium

The problem is that lithium sets the name depending on the id.
A radio group can't be grouped if the name is not the same.

Also, trying to nest to nest the group will be a problem due to the same issue with the name being different due to the IDs on the field being different, so using form->radio wouldn't help.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, they fixed that very recently[1]. Check the tests to see how to use it

```
$this->form->radio('foo', array('value' => 'nose'));
$this->form->radio('foo', array('checked' => true, 'value' => '1'));
```

[1] https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/lithium/pull/308